# Launching app from batch kills whole windows script

Tags: batch-file

After closing app script try to open it again. After oppening app and connecting to server script stops and nothing is continued.

```bat
:start
timeout /t 2
ping -n 1 10.0.0.1 | find "Reply" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto OFF
goto start

:OFF
taskkill /F /IM openvpn-gui.exe 
taskkill /F /IM openvpn.exe
timeout /t 3
"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect pgp.ovpn 
goto start 

:end
```

Comment: The code you have provided is a Windows batch-file. The question subject line has the word `bash` in it.  `BASH` is a completely different scripting language.  Please describe what `BASH` has to do with your `BATCH-FILE` code.

Comment: Searching for `Reply` might give you false positives. [Better use ' TTL=` as search string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397999/2152082) (As a bonus, it makes it language independent)